# How to build an external library downloaded with CMake FetchContent?

Tags: cmake

I have a program that depends on an external library (SDL for example). I want CMake to take care of that dependency for me, so I was looking into `FetchContent`. As far as I understand, this module simply downloads the source code so that information on the external library is available at *configure time*. For example:

```
include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(sdl
  GIT_REPOSITORY <...>
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(sdl)

# sdl_POPULATED, sdl_SOURCE_DIR and sdl_BINARY_DIR are ready now

if(NOT sdl_POPULATED)
  FetchContent_Populate(sdl)
endif()
```

At some point, however, I want to build that source code and link it to my main executable. How to do it the "modern CMake way"?

Comment: It depends on what the external lib provides build-wise.  E.g. if it builds with cmake you could add the lib to your build via a `add_subdirectory(${libname_SOURCE_DIR})` call.

I had a quick look at SDL. Looks like it doesn't build with cmake. In that case you could try to use https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html to build SDL (use the COMMAND keyword to invoke SDL's native build cmd) and then configure the custom target so that other targets can depend on it.  A great writeup how to do this: https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/

Comment: @Matt so basically if the library is a CMake-based one, i can just `add_subdirectory` and let CMake do the job for me. Otherwise I have to build it "by hand" with  `add_custom_target`. This is good to know, you could turn your comment into an answer :)

Comment: I've posted an answer.  After taking a second look at SDL it seems it actually *does* build with cmake ... maybe I landed on an outdated version, or looked at the wrong repo initially.  So that should hopefully make it easier to integrate it in your build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way to build external libraries from source as part of your build depends on what the external lib provides build-wise.

## External lib builds with cmake

If the external lib builds with cmake then you could add the lib to your build via a add_subdirectory(${libname_SOURCE_DIR}) call.  That way cmake will build the external lib as a subfolder ("subproject").  The `CMakeLists.txt` file of the external lib will have some `add_library(ext_lib_name ...)` statements in it.  In order to then *use* the external lib in your targets (an application or library that depends on the external lib) you can simply call  `target_link_libraries(your_application <PRIVATE|PUBLIC|INTERFACE> ext_lib_name)` https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html

I had a quick look at this github repo https://github.com/rantoniello/sdl - (let me know if you are referring to another library) and it actually looks like it is building with cmake and that it allows clients to statically or dynamically link against it: https://github.com/rantoniello/sdl/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L1688-L1740

So, ideally your applicaiton should be able to do

```
add_executable(myapp ...)
target_link_libraries(myapp PRIVATE SDL2-static) // Statically link againt SDL2
```

Due to their CMakeLists.txt file the `SDL2-static` comes with properties (include directories, linker flags/commands) that will automatically propergate to `myapp`.

## External lib does not build with cmake

If a external lib doesn't build with cmake then one can try to use `add_custom_target` https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html to build the library.  Something along the lines of:

```
add_custom_target(myExternalTarget COMMAND <invoke the repo's build system>)
```

You'd then need to set the target properties that are important for clients yourself via the the proper cmake functions `set_target_properties`, `target_include_directories` ...  A great writeup how to get started with these kinds of things: https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/